# how to attachment a file to an xml request with postman?

Tags: api, rest, soapui

Hello friend I need to make a request that I manage to do correctly from SOAP-UI but now in postmant , from SOAP-UI I do the following

I attchemnt a file and configure my request as follows

[image]

now I want to replicate this in postman but I don't know how to help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to send the bs64 inside the field

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).